# WebView2 not navigating to the given URL

Tags: .net, webview2

I have a .NET 6.0 app(say 'app2') that hosts and initializes the WebView2.
Now, the workflow is such that another app(say 'app1') calls the 'app2'.

Issue: I don't see WebView2 navigating to the given url and only a blank window when 'app2' is launched by 'app1',whereas if i launch 'app2' separately it does navigate.
Here is the code how i created and initialized WebView2:

```
private async Task InitializeWebView2()
{
    var webview = new WebView2();
    myPanel.Children.Add(webview);
    var env = await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
    await webview.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(env);
    string someUrl="http://google.com"; 
    webview.Source = new Uri(someUrl);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are specifying as your WebView2 Runtime folder path, the current directory of the process, which will be different depending on how your process is started. Instead of `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` you should more explicitly specify the path to your Fixed Version WebView2 Runtime folder. Perhaps something like, `this.GetType().Assembly.Location` assuming that the code above is in an assembly that's in the same folder as your Fixed Version WebView2 Runtime.

The first parameter to `CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync` is the folder that contains the WebView2 Runtime. If you are specifying an explicit path as you do above, then I'm assuming you are using your own Fixed Version copy of the WebView2 Runtime rather than using the shared Evergreen WebView2 Runtime.